# Why do none of my animations play when the view they're in is summoned from a modal segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, segue

I have a bunch of animations set to repeat that work beautifully if they're in their own view controller that is pushed to, but if I modally present them (via a modal segue from a UIButton tap) suddenly none of them play.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

This is an example of one animation being added:

```
UIView *topTapRipple1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(73, 30, 13.0, 13.0))];
topTapRipple1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
topTapRipple1.layer.cornerRadius = topTapRipple1.bounds.size.height/2;
topTapRipple1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.886 green:0.886 blue:0.886 alpha:1].CGColor;
topTapRipple1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[self.middleContentView insertSubview:topTapRipple1 belowSubview:self.middle];
```

Where that's the view that is added in order to create the animation. But that view never even gets added. Why is this?

Here's an example project replicating the issue: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/163k0D2f2L2P3H0E3y2i/animationtest.zip

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the animations in `viewDidLoad`, the segue animation isn't complete when you try to start them.  Try putting the animations in `viewDidAppear:`

Edit: This kind of animation would ideally be done with `CAAnimation` and `CALayer`. Creating and adding all those subviews seems like overkill.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second point with `CAAnimation` and `CALayer`?